# how to accept string array in java using bufferedreader

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

```
public static void accept_name( String[] name, int[] r)
{

   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader ab = new BufferedReader(isr);
    r = new int[40];
    name = new String[40];
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of students");
        name[i] = ab.readLine();
    }             
}
```

i am having a problem in name[i] = ab.readLine();

i don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: what is the problem you face??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Input\Output stream, an `IOException` is expected, define that it might throw that kind of exception:

```
public static void accept_name (String[] name, int[] r) throws IOException
{
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader ab = new BufferedReader(isr);

    r = new int[40];
    name = new String[40];

    for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of students");
        name[i] = ab.readLine();
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Actually,If you mouseover on the error line ,the message there tells everything.**

It's a compile time error.Asking for `exception` handling.While executing that line there are chances to get the `IOException`.

So you have to `handle` it by throwing in the `method` signature or by catching it there itself.

Change your method to

```
public static void accept_name( String[] name, int[] r)
    {

       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader ab = new BufferedReader(isr);
        r = new int[40];
        name = new String[40];
        for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of students");
            try {
                name[i] = ab.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }             
    }
```

[**Heavily recommending concept**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting name array in the function argument why are you initializing it again?
Below is not required

```
name = new String[40];
r = new int[40];
```

You code must be

```
public static void accept_name( String[] name, int[] r)
{

   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader ab = new BufferedReader(isr);
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of students");
        try {
            name[i] = ab.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }             
}
```

and then you can call your function as

```
String[] name = new String[40];
//populate your name array
int[] r = new int[40];
//populate your r array
ClassName.accept_name(name,r);//Static function
```

also I don't see where you are using r.

Comment: actuallly r is supposed to the roll nos of the students

Answer (score 0):

Readline throws an IOException so you should catch it or rethrow.

```
public static void accept_name(String[] name, int[] r) throws IOException {
 [...]
}
```

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
    public static void accept_name( String[] name, int[] r)
    {

       name = new String[40];
       for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
       {
            try {
                  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                  BufferedReader ab = new BufferedReader(isr);
                  System.out.println("Enter the name of students");
                  name[i] = ab.readLine();
                  ab.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }             
    }
```